# What is the most efficient program logic to not look through old data in VBA excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I remember a friend of mine telling me that is bad practice (and common mistake of programmers) to loop through entire databases to satisfy a condition, but instead you reference to them. However, the only way I know how to do what I want is to use the `For-Next` loop, `If-Then-End If` statements and using `Cut` and `Paste` macros to remove older data points, and use a `Filter` macro to only filter the dates of interest every time the code is ran.

I need a faster way because I created a fully automated payroll program using excel VBA that will run through 100,000 or more rows in a couple of years and even with only 6000 rows at the moment it's taking the program about 5 minutes to finish screening all the conditions and computations.

1.) Use a `For-Next` loop and `If-Then-End If` Loop

Let:

`Total_Rows_InSheet` be the total number of rows in the `Test` worksheet

`ActiveDate_Start` be the dates I want to compute only

Code Logic:

```
For i = 2 To Total_Rows_InSheet
    If Worksheets("Test").Cells(i, 2) >= ActiveDate_Start Then
        'run code'
    End If
Next i
```

2.) Transfer out the data using a cut/paste macro for the dates that should be archived in another worksheet, then the number of rows being computed will always be the active ones.

I want to limit the "active" data to a certain date range for my payroll application and I plan to cut out the rows of data where the payroll has already been issued to the employees from being re-computed. This is because there is no point in re-running to those data again because it'll make the program very slow.

3.) Similar to #2 just use a `Filter` macro to only filter dates greater than or equal to the `ActiveDate_Start`

Comment: Why not simply filter the table?

Comment: If your data is sorted by date and you know the date since when data is relevant (lets say relavant is from 2017-01-01 to now) then you can easily use the [WorksheetFunction.Match Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel) to find the row number of the date closest to `2017-01-01` and use that for start the loop. This would even be faster than filtering I think.

Comment: @jkpieterse Yup I added it at the same time as you posted actually almost crossed my mind. I think all these will work similarly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have some dates in column A that are sorted ascending (this does not work if not sorted!):

```
1   2015-01-01
2   2015-01-02
3   2015-01-03
4   2015-01-04
5   2016-12-30
6   2016-12-31
7   2017-01-01
8   2017-01-02
9   2017-01-03
10  2017-01-04
11  2017-01-05
12  2017-01-06
13  2017-01-07
14  2018-01-01
15  2018-01-02
16  2018-01-03
17  2018-01-04
18  2018-01-05
```

And your relevant data is between `2017-01-01` and `2018-01-01` you can use

```
Dim StartRow As Long
StartRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("2017-01-01", Range("A:A").Value, 1)

Dim EndRow As Long
EndRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("2018-01-01", Range("A:A").Value, 1)

Debug.Print StartRow, EndRow
```

to find the first and last row for your loop.

```
For i = StartRow To EndRow
    If Worksheets("Test").Cells(i, 2) >= ActiveDate_Start Then
        'run code'
    End If
Next i
```

Note that you might need some error handling for your `Match` functions as they throw errors when nothing is found.

Example:

```
Dim StartRow As Long
StartRow = 2 'fallback if match throws error
On Error Resume Next 'catch error of match
StartRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("2014-01-01", Range("A:A").Value, 1)
On Error GoTo 0 're-activate error reporting
```

Comment: Thanks i'll be doing some tests to see which performs fastest. If there are several dates that are of the same value, `Match` will still look at the first occurrence?

Comment: @MarcSantos no in this case it will find the last occurrence. But you can workaround this by eg. instead of `2017-01-01` you can look for the date one day earlier `2016-12-31` take its row and count +1 to get the first occurrence of `2017-01-01`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ If you change the last argument in match to 0, so **.Match("2014-01-01", Range("A:A").Value, 0)** wouldn't that find the first occurrence of the date?

Comment: @LuxClaridge It would. But only if `2014-01-01` is actually an exact match (and it is not even present in my example data). But it might be that there is no exact match for *every* date that you search for. That's why I used `1` to find the nearest date that exists in the data. So with my example it would find row number 2.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ oh right. I always use exact match and often forget how 1 and -1 do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1) Autofilter - this is a fast and efficient manner

2) Read everything into an array and perform the condition check there. An example of what that might look like.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SubSetArray()
    Dim i As Long, ActiveDate_Start As Long, arr(), outputArr(), counter As Long, j As Long '< or appropriate type
    ActiveDate_Start = 43269 'today's date as a number
    With Worksheets("Test")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        ReDim outputArr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If CLng(arr(i, 2)) >= ActiveDate_Start Then 'assumes date format in sheet so converts to Long
                counter = counter + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                    outputArr(counter, j) = arr(i, j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    outputArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)
    ReDim outputArr(1 To UBound(outputArr, 1), 1 To counter)
    outputArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Worksheets("OutputSheet").Range("A1")
    targetRange.Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), UBound(outputArr, 2)).Value = outputArr
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the advantage of #2 over using autofilter or the suggestion shown by @Pᴇʜ?

Comment: I like both of theirs to be honest. If looping an array, I don't think there will be a noticeable difference against knowing the start point for the loop if using arrays. Arrays will be faster than looping the sheet though. I suspect arrays may also be faster than autofilter but I have no evidence to base this on. I would need to test.

Comment: Thanks i'll be doing some tests to see which performs fastest

Comment: Which ended up fastest?

Comment: Still haven't tried. Quite busy with other things at the moment sorry might do so in a couple of days

Comment: No worries. :-) Would be interested to know.